# Markdown code block is broken by $ character

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I can't complete the following code block because of the `$` character in the regular expression.

````
```python
pattern = re.compile(r'\-[0-9]+$')
```
````

The last three ticks aren't closing the block so everything I write after is being interpreted as part of the code block.  Why is the `$` character doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: With which Markdown library? Or is this a question about a tool that uses Markdown, like GitHub?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It's in a jupyter notebook is all I know.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and I believe it is GitHub flavored

Comment: Might be a conflict with equations? https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#LaTeX-equations (This would be considered a bug.)

Comment: I see. It does go away if I add another $

Comment: I can't escape it because it's inside quotes.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I’m pretty sure it’s a bug.